# Dimension is preserved by normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How do I show that the dimension of a scheme is the same as its normalization's?

Let $v: \tilde X\rightarrow X$ be the normalization of $X$. I want to show that dim $\tilde X$ = dim $X$.

At first, I wanted to say that the dimensions should be equal because the normalization is a birational map that induces a bijection on the irreducible components. But this doesn't seem to be sufficient because of the following example I thought of: let $\pi: \Bbb A^1 \rightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is a line with a second line glued to its origin, so that the origin is the generic point of the second line. Then we have a birational map sending $\Bbb A^1 \setminus \{0\}$ to the equivalent subset of $Y$, which is dense there as well. However, dim $Y = 3$, so birational maps don't preserve dimension.

For the normalization, we have in addition that $\forall p\in \tilde X$, dim $\mathcal O_{\tilde X, p} =$ dim $\mathcal O_{X, v(p)}$, so dim $\tilde X \le$ dim $X$ But how do I get the other inequality?

Comment: The question is local, you may assume that $X=\textrm{Spec }A$ is affine (and integral), so that $\tilde X$ is the spectrum of the integral closure of $A$. But any integral extension of rings $A\subset B$ preserves the Krull dimension. This might be a strategy.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your example of $Y$ above? It seems to me $Y$ is nothing more than just $k[x,y]/(x^2 - y^2) = $  a figure $\mathsf{X}$ in the plane. And how is $Y$ three dimensional?

Comment: @Benja, my construction is more of a $+$ in the plane, but not the one given by Spec $k[x,y]/(xy)$. Instead, the generic point of the $Y$ axis is glued to the point $(x)$. So a chain of length three would be: generic point of the $X$ axis $\subset$ the origin of the $X$, (x), which is also the generic point of the $Y$ axis $\subset$ any point on the $Y$ axis.

Comment: @Brenin, I guess my problem is really in convincing myself that dimension is local, because of this counter-example I have in mind: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664753/dimension-is-local

Comment: @Rodrigo: Isn't that counterexample involving a space which is not even a ringed space (see the answer)? When dealing with normality, you only treat irreducible (actually, integral) schemes, so dimension *is* local on irreducible components, as there is only one; you have $\dim_xX=\dim X$ for any point $x\in X$.

Comment: @Brenin, yes that counter-example is flawed. However, I am working with a definition of Normalization that allows for a scheme with multiple irreducible components (Vakil defines a scheme to be normal if the stalks are integrally closed domains, so the disjoint union of two normal schemes is normal). When you wrote $\dim_x X$, you meant for any *closed* point, I'm sure. While I do see that my counterexample was wrong (because the local rings $k[x]_{(x)}$ and $k(y)$ are not isomorphic, so that I can't glue $(x_X)$ and $(0)$ together, I am still not quite satisfied with saying that

Comment: you can compute the dimension of an irreducible component on any of its closed points. What I prefer to use is my argument that I posted as an answer below. The reason is that I don't see yet that something topologically analogous to that counterexample couldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Given a scheme $X$ locally with finitely many irreducible components, one has that the normalization morphism $X^\nu\to X$ is integral and surjective, [035Q](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035Q). Now use [0ECG](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ECG).

Answer (score -1):

I guess a rigorous solution is this:

a normalization gives a bijection between the irreducible closed subsets. Since dimension is determined locally on any irreducible component that maximizes 'the dimension' (more precisely, that maximizes the maximal length of a chain of irreducible closed subsets), we can pick an affine open Spec $A \subset X$ that has that maximal dimension and look at its preimage Spec $B \subset \tilde X$. Then $A$ and $B$ have the same dimension, which gives us the other inequality.