# Dimension is local on irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples

I am having trouble to see that dimension of a scheme is local because I have the following counter-example in mind. I have a feeling this counter-example is fake because I can't find an open neighborhood around the "trouble point" that is isomorphic to an affine scheme.

Let $X =\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ and $Y\operatorname{Spec} k[y]$ be two lines and consider the scheme $Z$ obtained by gluing the generic point of $Y$, the prime $(0)$, to the origin of $X$, the maximal ideal $(x)$. Then $Z$, if it is indeed a scheme, should have dimension $2$, because the following is a chain of length three:

$$\text{the generic point of the X axis ⊂ the origin of the X, (x),}$$

$$\text{which is also the generic point of the Y axis ⊂ any point on the Y axis.}$$

Now, if this example were true, than dimension would not be local on irreducible components (note that $Z$ is irreducible), because one could pick several affine opens in $Z$ whose dimension is $1$. For example, $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]_x = \Bbb A_k^1 \setminus \{0\} \subset X \subset Z$.

My questions are: how can I show that $Z$ is not a scheme (i.e. that I can't pick any neighborhood around $(x_X)\sim (0_Y)$ that is isomorphic to an affine scheme), and how do I see that dimension is indeed local?

Comment: Dimension is not local -- it is the the maximum dimension of an irreducible component. What is the topology on this space? Is the glued point closed or not? It would seems that on one neighbourhood it is closed, and on another it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is not only not a scheme, it is not even a ringed space.  What is the local ring at the glued point?

You also need to be much more specific when saying "dimension is local".  For non-noetherian schemes, this could be a very ambiguous statement.  Furthermore, there are two different directions to prove, and you should specify which one you are struggling with—given a chain of primes, are you trying to produce a chain of closed subsets?  Or is it the other way around?

The first thing to understand is that the dimension of an affine variety, as a noetherian topological space, equals the dimension of its coordinate ring.  Once that connection is clear, I would look at arbitrary varieties.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I have two follow-up questions:
1) I do see now that it is not a ringed space because the local rings at the points that I tried to glue are not isomorphic, $k[x]_{(x)} \not \cong k(y)$. I realize now that this is a useful criterion to see if I glued things correctly -- the local ring of all points that are glued together must be the same. Is it a sufficient criterion?
2) While the way I constructed my example doesn't work, how can I see that something topologically like it could never happen in a scheme? Let me describe what topological pathology I mean:

Comment: I think of the generic point of an irreducible closed set as a point $g$ having infinitely many other points $p_i$ directly above it (think of it as tree with root $g$ and infinitely many branches coming out of it). Because there are infinitely many $p_i$ we can't write cl($g$) as the union of finitely many cl($p_i$) (the closure of a point contains all points sitting above it). Can we have an irreducible closed set, $\bar g$, such that some of the $p_i$ sitting above it are closed and some are not?

Comment: @Rodrigo 1) Probably not.  Gluing schemes over non-open sets is a slightly subtle matter.

Comment: @Rodrigo 2) We can; take the generic point of $\mathbb{A}^2$, for example, which has the generic point of any curve lying in its closure.  You shouldn't need this concept of "infinitely many", by the way—and it's not true in many schemes—you just need the observation that the generic point cannot lie in the closure of something else.  How to prove this depends on what your definition of "generic" is.  If $X$ is an integral scheme, then $\eta$, the generic point, lies in every nonempty open, and therefore cannot lie in any closure except its own (it is unique because schemes are $T_0$ spaces).

Comment: Well, what I meant is if we can have an irreducible closed set, $\bar g$, such that among the $p_i$ sitting *immediately* above it, some are closed, and some are open. The generic point of $\Bbb A^2$ doesn't satisfy this because the closed points above it are not immediately above it (you have to go through a vertex representing a curve to get to them). But I like your argument/definition that uses that the generic point is in all open sets.